# How do I fetch a list of model objects by querying another related model in a many to many relationship in DRF

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

models.py:

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
      image_number = models.CharField(max_length=20)
      title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
      image_url = models.URLField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
      image_size = models.CharField(max_length=50)
      file_type = models.CharField(max_length=20)
      price = models.CharField(max_length=50)

     def __str__(self):
         return self.title

class Order(models.Model):
      order_status = (
          ('created','created'), 
          ('processing','processing'),
          ('orderd','orderd')
        )
      user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True,null=True)
      items = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem)
      order_status = models.CharField(choices=order_status,null=True,max_length=50)
      start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
      ordered_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False,blank=True,null=True)
```

views.py:

```
class AddtocartView(generics.CreateAPIView):
      authentication_classes = []
      permission_classes = []
      pagination_class = None
      queryset = OrderItem.objects.all()
      serializer_class = AddtocartSerializers

    def perform_create(self,serializer):
        new_order_item = serializer.save()
        user=CustomUser.objects.filter(id=self.kwargs['customer_id']).first() 

        try:
           orders_list = Order.objects.get(user=user)            
           orders_list.items.add(new_order_item) 
        except Order.DoesNotExist: 
            order = Order.objects.create(user=user) 
            order.items.add(new_order_item)  


       def __str__(self):
           return str(self.user)
```

urls.py:

```
 path('customer/<int:customer_id>/addtocart/',views.AddtocartView.as_view(),name='addtocart'),
 path('customer/<int:customer_id>/cart/',views.CartView.as_view(),name='cart'),
```

[image]

Everything working fine. when I run `perform_create` API it checks if there is an existing `created` order and if there is one then it adds the `OrderItem` to `items`, else it will create an order. So my issue is when the user makes the payment and `Order.status` changes to `ordered` then how I'm gonna fetch the ordered items and cart item.
So I was thinking I should create an order for every `OrderItem` then if the order is completed it will change the `Order.status` to `ordered` otherwise it will be `created`. That way I will fetch the `created` to cart and `ordered` to **Ordered page**. any suggestion, on how I am can enhance this logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understood in your question, you want an API that retrieves `OrderItem`s based on their related `Order` status. **Correct me in the comments if I was mistaken**

In order to keep this logic clean,

I recommend you to let go that idea of creating an `Order` for each `OrderItem`

What I believe is going to work for you, is creating an API for OrderItems, lets call it `OrdersItemsListViewAPI` with `Order`, and do filtering based on `Order.status` based on url param **ex: `.../orders/items?status=created`**, that way you will get only `created` orders, or `ordered` orders, ..etc

A simple example for this

```
class OrdersItemsListViewAPI(generics.ListAPIView):
    """
    Return a list of all the products that the authenticated
    user has ever purchased, with optional filtering.
    """
    serializer_class = OrderItemSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        # You are using a custom user, make sure you get the custom user to do the query below.
        user = self.request.user
        status = self.request.query_params.get('status', None)
        # To make sure you are getting user's orders
        orders = Order.objects.filter(user=user)
        if status:
            # Filtering user's orders to get specific status
            orders = orders.filter(order_status=status)
        # Now get All OrderItems that belong to fetched orders.
        return OrderItem.objects.filter(order__in=orders)
```

**Update**: In order to filter based on multiple statuses, just pass the statuses comma-separated in your query param `?status=created,ordered`, and extract them inside your `get_queryset` method, like the following.

```
...
    def get_queryset(self):
        # You are using a custom user, make sure you get the custom user to do the query below.
        user = self.request.user
        status = self.request.query_params.get('status', None)
        # To make sure you are getting user's orders
        orders = Order.objects.filter(user=user)
        if status:
            # Filtering user's orders to get specific status
            status = [s.strip() for s in status.split(',')]
            orders = orders.filter(order_status__in=status)
        # Now get All OrderItems that belong to fetched orders.
        return OrderItem.objects.filter(order__in=orders)
```

This way you are keeping your models well structured with a slight of modification on your controller.

I've tested this code on a similar scenario, and it works perfectly.

Comment: okay you are right but still some confusion assume status is created you are getting order who has status created but why are you filtering order_id in orders_ids as orderitem dont have order_id field

Comment: as one order can have multiple orderitem how can i filter based on status from order models

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, I did this as OneToMany relation, I will update my answer in a bit

Comment: you are filtering user then order_status but one user have one order with multiple orderitems

Comment: see the image if i get created status it will show all the orderitem belong to user

Comment: what i want that get orderitem whose status is created or ordered based on query

Comment: If you want both statuses, you can simple pass the query param with `?status=created,ordered`, and inside the `if status` block, just split these 2, and do the filter like this `orders.filter(order_status__in=status.split(','))`, this way you will have or'ing between statuses.

Comment: when you do `OrderItem.objects.filter(order__in=orders)`, you will get all **`OrderItems`** that are related to these orders.

Comment: that what i am saying it means i have to create order for every orderitem

Comment: Nope, you just need to append `items` on the `order` with the item you are going to add to your cart.

Why would you create a new order for each order item, they already have a Many-To-Many relationship, with a join table.

Comment: okay but its not filtering every orderitem who has order_status created. its filtering order who has order_status created

Comment: i am assuming i already filtered user suppose i have i have add two orderitem to items now it will look for order_status created then it will return the all the orderitem of this order because orderitem doesn't have any filed to filter. point me if i am wrong

Comment: I updated the answer, with how you are going to filter based on multiple statues, and in the case of no filtering parameter provided you will get all `OrderItems`.

Comment: i think you didn't understand i'm saying orderitem table doesn't have order_status fileld. its in order table so how i'm going to filter orderitem whose orderstatus is lets says created

Comment: The same way I've explained in my answer bro, get all `Orders` that matches your filtering criteria, then filter `OrderItems` table base on the returned orders!!!!

Comment: you are returning this OrderItem.objects.filter(order__in=orders) but orderitem doesn't have order column